# Android Chat with own resources / Pull data live from server

Tags: android, chat

I started with a application where you can chat.
Now im in the position to start with the chat.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't want to use 
resources from "outside". With outside I mean:
Firebase, Socket.io and so on.

I do simply rent a webspace. And I'm asking you now, 
how is it possible to realize an live chat without
using extern services like firebase.

Is it possible with only using an Webspace?
What is **required** to make an live chat?

And there comes the second question:

How do I realize to stay connected to a server to check if there is a new message without using much battery or network ressources?

---

I'm not asking without hardly trying by my self.
Two days ago I started with the research of possibility, but I didn't found anything which would work I guess.

Thanks folks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the Web Server using a Socket and keep that connection open to receive new messages with little delay (see for example http://srchea.com/build-a-real-time-application-using-html5-websockets) This keeps the phone active and uses much battery.

The very purpose of Firebase is to bundle this work for all services which need this type of communication (E-Mail, Push messages of newspapers, Chats) such that the phone only has to query *one* server. Therefore, I see no way for you to find another solution which uses little battery.